# java.io.EOFException while writing and reading froma servlet

Tags: java, objectoutputstream, objectinputstream, eofexception

I have the following code on the applet side:

```
URL servlet = new URL(appletCodeBase, "FormsServlet?form=requestRoom");
URLConnection con = servlet.openConnection();

con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setUseCaches(false);
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
out.writeObject(user);//user is an object of a serializable class
out.flush();
out.close();

ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(con.getInputStream());
status = (String)in.readObject();
in.close();
if("success".equals("status")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Request submitted successfully.");
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "ERROR! Request cannot be made at this 
    time");
}
```

In the servlet side I recieve the code as follows:

```
    form = request.getParameter("form");
    if("requestRoom".equals(form)) {
        String fullName, eID, reason;
        UserRequestingRoom user;

        try {
            in = new ObjectInputStream(request.getInputStream());
            user = (UserRequestingRoom)in.readObject();
            fullName = user.getFullName();
            eID = user.getEID();
            reason = user.getReason();

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chat_applet","root","");
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO REQCONFROOM VALUES(\"" + fullName + "\",\"" + eID + "\",\"" + reason + "\")");
            statement.execute();

            out = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
            out.writeObject("success");
            out.flush();

        } catch (Exception e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
            out.writeObject("fail");
            out.flush();
        }
    }
```

When I click on the button that calls the code in the applet side, I get the following error:

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.org.RequestRoomForm.requestActionPerformed(RequestRoomForm.java:151)

    **//Line 151 is "ObjectInputStream in..." line in the applet code**

    at com.org.RequestRoomForm.access$000(RequestRoomForm.java:7)
    at com.org.RequestRoomForm$1.actionPerformed(RequestRoomForm.java:62)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Why am I getting this error? I have flushed when I output, I have closed the connections also, yet I get the error. Any reason for this?

Comment: Have you debugged your servlet (or at least made some log outputs) to make sure that you actually reach the servlet and enter the if block? From the client side exception, it looks as if the servlet (or some other server component) is not writing anything to the response stream, so that the client fails immediately due to the empty response.

Comment: yes. It doesn't show any indication that the execution reaches servlet. Anyway, I had to split my serializable obejct and send it through the URl itself (via &). The result is too crude - a very lengthy URL. But it does the job in the end.

Answer (score 10):

**Close the ObjectOutputStream at the end.**

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
out.writeObject(user);//user is an object of a serializable class
out.flush();
out.close(); //Don,t close your out here

ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(con.getInputStream());
status = (String)in.readObject();
in.close();

out.close(); //Close your out after reading the input
```

Answer (score -2):

first `request.getParameter()` 
then `request.getInputStream()`

this case must course exception on tomcat ,but not course exception on weblogic